# Mascara de Data no EditText

Tags: java, android

Como colocar mascara de data no `EditText` do Android, de forma que fique `dd/mm/aaaa` ?

Comment: Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

Eu costumo usar um `Masked Edittext` nesse caso, onde o componente faz tudo pra gente.

Basta dar uma olhada no Git https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText

No seu caso ficaria algo assim:

```
  <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
        android:id="@+id/initial_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        app:mask="##/##/####"
        android:inputType="date" />
```

Note o atributo `mask`, é ele que voce irá editar conforme for preciso.

**EDIT**

Hoje em dia eu uso uma classe em Kotlin para tratar isso, que é bem semelhante ao o que o Viana postou abaixo. Passo para ela como parametro o edit text e o tipo de mascara no formato `##/##/####`.
Segue o código dela:

```
 class MyMaskEditText(var editText: EditText, protected var mMask: String) : TextWatcher {


private var isUpdating: Boolean = false
protected var mOldString = ""
internal var befores = ""

override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    befores = s.toString().replace("[^\\d]".toRegex(), "")

}

override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    var str = s.toString().replace("[^\\d]".toRegex(), "")

    if (str.length == 0) {
        return
    }

    if (before == 1 && befores.length > 0 && !isUpdating) {
        val last = befores.substring(befores.length, befores.length)
        val rep = last.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").replace("-", "")
        if (rep.length == 0) {
            str = str.substring(0, befores.length - 1)
        }
    }


    val mask = StringBuilder()
    if (isUpdating) {
        mOldString = str
        isUpdating = false
        return
    }
    var i = 0
    for (m in mMask.toCharArray()) {
        if (m != '#') {
            mask.append(m)
            continue
        }
        try {
            mask.append(str[i])
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            break
        }

        i++
    }
    isUpdating = true
    val x = mask.toString()
    editText.setText(x)
    editText.setSelection(mask.length)

}

override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
}
 }
```

Para usar, pode criar uma extension para ficar mais fácil de visualizar.

```
fun EditText.myCustomMask(mask: String) {
addTextChangedListener(MyMaskEditText(this, mask))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente o Android não oferece uma classe nativa para esse tipo de ação, portanto, é possível fazer isso usando uma combinação de números e caracteres especiais.

Existem algumas *libs* que pode fazer isso, como:

- [Masked-Edittext](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext)
- [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText)
- [edittext-mask](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)
- [input-mask-android](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android)

Entretanto, a regra básica que essas *libs* podem estar usando é: usar o método `addTextChangeListener` para verificar o que está sendo digitado no campo de texto, `EditText`. Desta forma, realizar alguma ação toda vez que o ouvidor obter alguma mudança.

Veja abaixo a classe `Mask`, no qual possui um método `insert` que recebe como parâmetro a mascara desejada (`##/##/####`) e o `EditText` e faz o tratamento usando expressão regular.

```
public abstract class Mask {

    public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText et) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isUpdating;
            String oldTxt = "";
            public void onTextChanged(
                CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
                String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
                String maskCurrent = "";
                if (isUpdating) {
                    oldTxt = str;
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }
                int i = 0;
                for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                    if (m != '#' && str.length() > oldTxt.length()) {
                        maskCurrent += m;
                        continue;
                    }
                    try {
                        maskCurrent += str.charAt(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                isUpdating = true;
                et.setText(maskCurrent);
                et.setSelection(maskCurrent.length());
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(
                CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        };
    }
    private static String unmask(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
                .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
                .replaceAll("[)]", "");
    }
}
```

Como usar:

```
EditText etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
etDate.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##/##/####", etDate));
```

Veja também [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889503/2570426) no qual possui uma solução muito próxima desta.

Aqui também na pergunta sobre [Máscara de CPF/Cnpj em Edittext](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108591/m%C3%A1scara-de-cpf-cnpj-em-edittext) possui uma solução que serve para você, basta apenas modificar a mascara desejada.

Answer (score 1):

Preferi escrever meu código. É apenas uma simples função, apenas colar e usar. obs: Está em kotlin.

Crie a seguinte função:

```
fun dateWatcher( editText:EditText) {

    var oldString : String = ""

    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        var changed: Boolean = false

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            changed = false



        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) 
        {
            //changed=false
            editText.setSelection(p0.toString().length)
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            var str: String = p0.toString()

            if (str != null) {

                if (oldString.equals(str)) {
                    //significs que o user esta apagando
                    //do Nothing

                } else if (str.length == 2) {  //  xx
                    var element0: String = str.elementAt(0).toString()
                    var element1: String = str.elementAt(1).toString()
                    str = element0 + element1 + "/"
                    editText.setText(str)
                    oldString = element0 + element1
                    editText.setSelection(str.length)

                } else if (str.length == 5) { //  xx/xx

                    var element0: String = str.elementAt(0).toString() //x
                    var element1: String = str.elementAt(1).toString() //-x
                    var element2: String = str.elementAt(2).toString() //--/
                    var element3: String = str.elementAt(3).toString() //--/x
                    var element4: String = str.elementAt(4).toString() //--/-x

                    str = element0 + element1 + element2 + element3 + element4 + "/"
                    editText.setText(str)
                    oldString = element0 + element1 + element2 + element3 + element4
                    editText.setSelection(str.length)

                } else if (str.length > 8) { // este exemplo é para data no formato xx/xx/xx. Se você quer usar xx/xx/xxxx mudar para if (str.length >10). O resto do código permanece o mesmo.

                    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1)
                    editText.setText(str)
                    editText.setSelection(str.length)

                }


            }

        }
    })
}
```

Para usar este método faça assim:

```
dateWatcher(seuEditTextAqui)
```

Comment: O código é bom, mas a pergunta foi feita em java. Sempre é bom respeitar as tags,  mesmo que mesclar Java e Kotlin seja o apenas trabalho de compilar uma classe extra.