# Máscara em TextEdit

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um **form** de entrada de combustível e eu precisava de uma máscara de litros que tivesse 3 campos após a virgula. Exemplo:

> 002.555 Litros

Eu precisava que o campo já viesse preenchido com **"000.000"** e que, fosse **preenchido de trás pra frente** conforme o usuário for digitando.

É possível montar uma máscara dessa maneira?

Comment: Aqui tem uma resposta parcial, só precisa adaptar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207432/35406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem uma biblioteca desenvolvida por `jansenfelipe`, você pode encontrar um tutorial [neste link](https://jansenfelipe.com.br/2015/05/08/android-como-inserir-mascara-em-um-edittext/)

mais basicamente você precisa adicionar a seguinte dependencia:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'br.com.jansenfelipe:androidmask:1.0.1'
}
```

Após isto basta criar a máscara conforme a necessidade:

```
EditText cpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPF);
EditText tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefone);

//Mascara cpf
MaskEditTextChangedListener maskCPF = new MaskEditTextChangedListener("###.###.###-##", cpf);
//Mascara Telefone
MaskEditTextChangedListener maskTEL = new MaskEditTextChangedListener("(##)####-####", tel);
```

O último passo é adicionar este listener ao campo:

```
cpf.addTextChangedListener(maskCPF);
tel.addTextChangedListener(maskTEL);
```

Com relação ao preenchido de trás pra frente você pode utilizar o `setGravity` para apontar de onde o texto começa, por exemplo:

```
cpf.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
tel.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

ou no `xml` com o atributo

```
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

Comment: Mas e o preenchido de trás pra frente ?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `.setGravity` editei a resposta

Comment: Funcionou 100%!
Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```java
public String mascaraDouble(Double myDouble){
    String result = String.format("%1$,.3f", myDouble);
    return result;
}
```

O `String.format` é muito rico em opções, esse [link](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) tem alguns bons exemplos

Comment: Mas e o preenchido de trás pra frente?